# Agrupar valores en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, array

tengo un problema con la agrupación de datos de un json, les explico, tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
var dato = [
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", CI-02: 123},
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", CI-03: 123}
]
```

y necesito agrupar por fechas, junto con sus siguientes apartado, de tal manera quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
var dato = [
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", CI-02: 123, CI-03: 123}
]
```

soy principiante en javascript, y me es necesario tener el resultado anterior para poder llenar una tabla de agGritvue en vue.js

Alguien podria ayudarme para poder resolverse estaré agradecido, de antemano gracias

Comment: Podrías adjuntar el código con el que has intentado lograrlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero sea lo que requieres. Mira la libreria **lodash** que se usa y las consideraciones aplicadas.

```js
//  Observa que el dato despues de "fecha" esta como texto ya que no se permite guiones en los nombres
var dato = [
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", "CI-02": 123},
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", "CI-03": 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", "CI-04": 128} /* Este lo agregue para que se observe se obtienen todos */
];

var resultante=new Array();

// Se hace uso de una libreria LODASH para simplificar
// Primero obtenemos las fechas únicas.
resultante = _.sortedUniq(_.map(dato, function(value) {
    var nvoObjeto = {fecha: value.fecha};
    
    // De todos los datos obtenemos los que corresponde a la "fecha" que se esta procesando
    _.forEach(_.filter(dato, function(o) { return o.fecha==nvoObjeto.fecha; }), function (valuef) {
      // Revisamos cada una de las propiedades
      _.forEach(valuef, function (propValuef, keyF) {
        // Agregamos esta cuando no sea "fecha"; ojo, se asume que no habra 2 objetos con la misma propiedad
        if (keyF!="fecha") nvoObjeto[keyF]=propValuef;
      });
    });
    
    return nvoObjeto;
}));

console.log(resultante);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gracias me cumplió lo que necesitaba te agradezco

Answer (score 2):

Bastaría escribir tu propia función de comparación basado en la propiedad fecha

```js
var dato = [
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", CI_02: "123"},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", CI_02: 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", CI_02: 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", CI_02: 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", CI_02: 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", CI_02: 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", CI_02: 123},
    {fecha: "15/06/2019", CI_03: 123},
    {fecha: "16/06/2019", CI_03: 123},
    {fecha: "17/06/2019", CI_03: 123},
    {fecha: "18/06/2019", CI_03: 123},
    {fecha: "19/06/2019", CI_03: 123},
    {fecha: "20/06/2019", CI_03: 123},
    {fecha: "21/06/2019", CI_03: 123}
];

function compare( a, b ) {
  if ( a.fecha < b.fecha ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.fecha > b.fecha ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log(dato.sort(compare));
```

Para invertir el orden de clasificación(ascendente o descendente), puede invertir el valor de retorno de la función compare.

Comment: Pero no es eso lo que está pidiendo! Él quiere agrupar los datos según la fecha!